# custom nginx deployment fails to start in kubernetes

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, dockerfile

I'm trying to deploy a custom nginx container in to a k8s cluster but the pod is failing to start. Below is from k8s,

```
Namespace:        demo
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             ip-10-148-127-81.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal/10.148.127.81
Start Time:       Thu, 06 Oct 2022 22:14:33 +1100
Labels:           app=my-nginx
                  pod-template-hash=8d45cdd7f
Annotations:      kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
Status:           Running
IP:               10.148.127.119
IPs:
  IP:           10.148.127.119
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/my-nginx-8d45cdd7f
Containers:
  my-nginx:
    Container ID:   docker://3a2f9753e67b4897e24ef83f7548302cfd0360306f082556d2f9d888f6c4938f
    Image:          bindo/mynginx-test:v1
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://whispir/k8scd-demo@sha256:2389496c7800484fff93db1f950e748ca3f9f9102dc7fe90f93164974206dc07
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Thu, 06 Oct 2022 22:17:51 +1100
      Finished:     Thu, 06 Oct 2022 22:17:51 +1100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  5
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-4p25s (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-4p25s:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-4p25s
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  4m46s                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned demo/my-nginx-8d45cdd7f-dcsks to ip-10-148-127-81.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
  Normal   Pulled     4m40s                  kubelet            Successfully pulled image "bindo/mynginx-test:v1" in 4.782833718s
  Normal   Pulled     4m38s                  kubelet            Successfully pulled image "bindo/mynginx-test:v1" in 2.493401759s
  Normal   Pulled     4m23s                  kubelet            Successfully pulled image "bindo/mynginx-test:v1" in 2.521480151s
  Normal   Created    3m56s (x4 over 4m40s)  kubelet            Created container my-nginx
  Normal   Started    3m56s (x4 over 4m40s)  kubelet            Started container my-nginx
  Normal   Pulled     3m56s                  kubelet            Successfully pulled image "bindo/mynginx-test:v1" in 2.475891781s
  Warning  BackOff    3m18s (x8 over 4m37s)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
  Normal   Pulling    3m3s (x5 over 4m45s)   kubelet            Pulling image "bindo/mynginx-test:v1"
```

Heres the DockerFile used to build the said image

```
 FROM nginx
 RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y; \
   echo "Hello World" > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
 EXPOSE 8080
 CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Heres the deployment manifest used.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: demo
  name: mynginx
  labels:
    app: mynginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mynginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mynginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mynginx
        image: bindo/mynginx-test:v1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
```

Below are the commands that were used to build/tag/push from my local machine

```
docker build . -t bindo/mynginx-test
docker tag bindo/mynginx-test bindo/mynginx-test:v1
docker push bindo/mynginx-test:v1
```

Please can someone advice what I'm doing wrong here? TIA

Comment: The container itself seems to be crashing, is there any information in the pod logs?

Comment: No nothing at all except what I've posted under "from k8s" section